# Best cloth for a poster

Tags: poster, technology

I am printing a poster for presenting at a conference. I would like to print on cloth so that I can carry it easily in the suitcase.

In many print shops I have to select which cloth exactly to print on. There are many kinds of clothes: satin, canvas, flag, net, etc...

Which material both allows a high printing resolution (so that the details are clearly visible), and remains good-looking after transporting it in a suitcase?

Comment: choose a material with a fine weave ie highest number of threads per inch...

Comment: I feel like the print shop is in the best position to advise you on that

Comment: @LyndonWhite most print-shops I asked mainly produce posters for advertisement outdoors - the considerations for such posters are quite different than for an academic poster.

Answer (score 6):

I always use canvas. My experience says it is great to fold, carry and fix in the board. The printing quality is also excellent, even Arial 10-12 point font size looks very clear in the graphs. Moreover you can fold it in any form. I always make a square/rectangular fold and carry it in my backpack. It never erase any printings. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Polyester that is dense and supports bright colors is great. I've posted a bit about cloth posters [here](https://eighteenthelephant.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/a-soft-silky-scientific-poster/) -- see especially the "update" at the bottom, which notes the excellent "performance knit" fabric from Spoonflower.